# Post specific text based on category displayed

Tags: text, categories

So I'm working on a site and I need a news page that is slightly different. It is a post category but I want the text echoed at the top of the news category listing.

```
<?php endif; ?>
<?php /* If this is a category archive */ if (is_category()) { ?>               
    <h2>Board: <?php echo single_cat_title(); ?></h2>
<?php /* If this is a daily archive */ } elseif (is_category('news')) { ?>
    <h2>News: </h2>
<?php /* If this is a daily archive */ } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
    <h2>Daily Archive | Board: <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></h2>
<?php /* If this is a monthly archive */ } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
    <h2>Monthly Archive | Board: <?php the_time('F, Y'); ?></h2>
<?php /* If this is a yearly archive */ } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
    <h2>Yearly Archive | Board: <?php the_time('Y'); ?></h2>
<?php /* If this is a search */ } elseif (is_search()) { ?>
    <h2>Search Results: </h2>
<?php /* If this is an author archive */ } elseif (is_author()) { ?>
    <h2>Author Archive: </h2>
<?php /* If this is a paged archive */ } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?>
    <h2>Archives: </h2>
<?php } ?>
```

This code works fine for archives except the fact that `<?php /* If this is a daily archive */ } elseif (is_category('news')) { ?>
        <h2>News: </h2>` does not work when you view the news category. It shows the standard text for every other category.

Then if you do `<?php if (is_category('News')) : ?>
            <p>News:</p>
        <?php else : ?>` it works and shows that text when viewing the news category. How do I get it to work so that when you view the news category it shows one specific set of text at the top of the page? Because the methods I have tried do not seem to be working.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is to use a category template and let WordPress step through its template hierarchy and display the News template when it is called.

So you would copy your theme's category.php to category-news.php (assuming the slug is "news") and then edit that file to place whatever text you want where ever you want it.

[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)